# Equation align to '=' in table with cell equation

Tags: tables, equations, align

```
            \begin{center}
                \begin{tabular}{ ||l|r@{ = }p{4cm}|| } 
                    \hline
                    Text & \multicolumn{2}{l||}{Text}\\
                    \hline
                    $E_1 \rightarrow E_2 + E_3$     & $E_1.type$ & $max(\textbf{b}, \textbf{c}) = \textbf{i}$ \\
                                                    &      $a_1$ & $f(\textbf{id}_2, \textbf{t}, \textbf{z})$\\
                                                    &            & \begin{equation}
                                                                    \left\{
                                                                        \begin{align}
                                                                            t_1 &= \textbf{new}\;Temp() 
                                                                            gen(t_1 &= (\textbf{int}) \textbf{id}_2)
                                                                            & \textbf{return} t_1
                                                                        \end{align} 
                                                                    \right.
                                                                    \end{equation}

                    \hline

                \end{tabular}
            \end{center}
```

I'm trying to have is like a left bracket for that whole equation and keep the '=' aligned in the table.

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE! Nice WME, most likely in this type of question posting an image of your output (using the provided tools) would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with 'cases'

```
$\begin{cases}
    t_1 = \textbf{new}\;Temp() \\
    gen(t_1 = (\textbf{int}) \textbf{id}_2)\\
    \textbf{return} t_1
\end{cases}$
```